# Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline

Tags: discussion, top-7

### The Elevator Pitch

This isn't as easy as it sounds. Imagine the user who will never read your FAQ and you have two seconds to grab their attention. It should be catchy but descriptive. It should be thoroughly clear but painfully concise. **Make every... word... count.**

Here are some creative examples:

- [Gawker](http://gawker.com/): Daily Manhattan media news and gossip. Reporting live from the center of the universe.
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/): The gadget guide. So much in love with shiny new toys, it’s unnatural.
- [Autoblog](http://www.autoblog.com/): We obsessively cover the auto industry.
- [DumbLittleMan](http://www.dumblittleman.com/): So what do we do here? Well, it’s simple. 15 to 20 times per week we provide tips that will save you money, increase your productivity, or simply keep you sane.
- [Needcoffee.com](http://www.needcoffee.com/): We are the Internet equivalent of a triple espresso with whipped cream. Mmmm…whipped cream.

### Use it as a Tagline

A shorter elevator pitch *can* be used as a tagline — something you can display in the header at the top of the page. If it doesn't fit, consider shortening it or creating a separate tagline. Here are some great examples:

- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/): News for nerds. Stuff that matters.
- [Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/): Don’t live to geek, geek to live!
- [The Simple Dollar](http://www.thesimpledollar.com/): Financial talk for the rest of us.

### The Motto (don't forget your logo)

A logo begs for it own little, short tagline — like a motto. Maybe the tagline inspires the logo; Maybe it's the other way around. Mottos make good t-shirt, bumper stickers, and other marketing material. Either way, you'll recognize a good motto when you see it:

- Just do it.
- Think Different.
- The Uncola.
- Intel inside.
- Like a rock.
- The king of beers.

…and perhaps all this leads to a proper name and domain for your site… *eventually*. So let's start from the basics. **Come up with a killer elevator pitch, tagline, and/or motto!**

Comment: While the question is fair enough in principle, I would much prefer just a question for names (separately). Personally, I don't care much if this site has a motto.

Comment: What is [meta-tag:top-7]?

Answer (score 1):

## Quantum of knowledge

Just to get this barest seed of an idea out there, the phrase comes to mind. I'm not sure what we could do with it. If you have ideas, edit them in.

Comment: This name sounds too similar to that of a Bond film flop!

Comment: (At least that's what it may conjure up in many people's minds.)

Answer (score 1):

## Answers to the multiverse's most basic questions. And some trivial ones too.

I'm not sold on the word 'trivial' though, suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't panic! Now the force is with you!

(Hitch-hiker's guide to the galaxy and StarWars combined :)

Answer (score 0):

## Einstein asks, Schrödinger answers